# How to sample from a normal distribution restricted to a certain interval, C++ implementation?

Tags: c++, distribution, normal-distribution

With [this function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/) I can sample from a normal distribution. I was wondering how could I sample efficiently from a normal distribution restricted to a certain interval `[a,b]`. My trivial approach would be to sample from the normal distribution and then keep the value if it belongs to a certain interval, otherwise re-sample. However would probably discards many values before I get a suitable one.

I could also approximate the normal distribution using a triangular distrubution, however I don't think this would be accurate enough.

I could also try to work on the cumulative function, but probably this would be slow as well. Is there any efficient approach to the problem?

Thx

Comment: It's not clear to me if you want to sample from an interval [a,b] of a Normal Distribution over (-inf,+inf) or sample from a Normal Distribution over [a,b]. Or something else?

Comment: I want to sample from a truncated normal distribution over [a,b]. I.e. I want to sample a value x with probability 0 if x is not in [a,b] otherwise it has to have a normal distribution.

Comment: Compute p((-inf,a)) and p((b,inf)). Subtract them from one. Divide the old formula for p((x,y)) with x<y in [a,b] by that value and you have your adjusted probability. You can also apply that to other formulas.

Comment: @Aziuth I'm not sure what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Aziuth, the question is how to sample from this interval distribution - not calculate a probability.

Comment: Another approach I was thinking was sampling many times from a uniform distribution in [a,b] the mean should be distributed according to a normal distribution.

Comment: @JimmyNJ That's why I said that it can be applied to other formulas. A formula that computes such a sample could be adapted using what I wrote. Dunno the formula of those, though. Easy but inefficient would be to create a uniformly distributed sample s in [0,1] and then find x so that p((-inf,x]) = s by halving intervals until a value for x is found s.th. the difference of p((-inf,x)) and s is below some threshold. Or to do this by creating an array for some discrete steps of x in before, if the accuracy does not have to be that high.

Comment: @Aziuth Could you elaborate more your proposal in an answer? I can't really get your point...

Comment: I'm somewhat hesitant to create an answer out of an inefficient approach.  I suppose that you have (the implementation of) some way to compute a sample for a normal distribution, and all I say is how you can modify this for your needs. For example, if you have code that effectively inverts the cumulative distribution function (F_X(x) := p(X <= x)), you could simply add the factor I stated in that implementation. Then I continued about inefficient examples how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you know how to transform to and from standard normal with shifting by μ and scaling by σ.

Option 1, as you said, is acceptance/rejection.  Generate normals as usual, reject them if they're outside the range [a, b].  It's not as inefficient as you might think.  If p = P{a < Z < b}, then the number of trials required follows a geometric distribution with parameter p and the expected number of attempts before accepting a value is 1/p.

Option 2 is to use an inverse Gaussian function, such as the one in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/inverse_gaussian_dist.html).  Calculate lo = Φ(a) and hi = Φ(b), the probabilities of your normal being below a and b, respectively.  Then generate U distributed uniformly between lo and hi, and crank the resulting set of U's through the inverse Gaussian function and rescale to get outcomes with the desired truncated distribution.

Comment: For clarity:  Gaussian and Normal Distributions are different names for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The normal distribution is an integral, see the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution):

```
std::cout << "riemann_midpnt_sum = " << 1 / (sqrt(2*PI)) * riemann_mid_point_sum(fctn, -1, 1.0, 100) << '\n';

// where fctn is the function inside the integral
double fctn(double x) {
    return exp(-(x*x)/2);
}
```

output: "riemann_midpnt_sum = 0.682698"
This calculates the normal distribution (standard) from -1 to 1.

This is using a riemman sum approximate the integral. You can take the riemman sum from [here](https://github.com/fernanluyano/numerical-methods)

Answer (score -1):

You could have a look at the implementation of the normal dist function in your standard library (e.g., https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00277.html), and figure out a way to re-implement this with your constraint.

It might be tricky to understand the template-heavy library code, but if you really need speed then the trivial approach is not well suited, particularly if your interval is quite small.